# How to use a NBT Editor

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

Okay so i want to change the value of a item with a NBT editor. The value i want to change is the stack limit. The steps that i did was

1. Placed a few stackable blocks in my inventory
2. Found my level.dat
3. Placed it inside [THIS](https://irath96.github.io/webNBT/) website
4. Then i Players -> Inventory
5. Found the items im holding in

But i don't know how to change the value so you can't stack any items at all!

Comment: Are you the same person as the one who asked the last "how to make items unstackable" questions?

Comment: What are you talking about?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The stack limit is a property of the game. NBTEdit can only edit data that the game can handle. You can't modify the game itself with it.

Comment: Okay thanks for the help! But is there any other way to change the value with etc command blocks or such? Or if you could do it another way?

Comment: Someone asked something similar before and the short answer is "if you are willing to put a month into it, but it won't work well. Try changing the texture of unstackable items instead". But sure, you can look up "decompile minecraft" and then replace every 64 in the code with a 1. But that will only work if both client and server are modded.